# Unity need character to rotate to face movement direction on planetoid

Tags: c#

we are working on a student project and we chose to do a Mario Galaxy style platformer with planetoids and gravity (kind of a big mistake for my first coding project but I cannot back out of it now) but I am having a hard time to get the character to face it's movement direction without absolutely spazzing out.

I have only been coding for around 2 months so please excuse me being useless at trying to figure this out.

This is the code I use for movement for the character

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SC_RigidbodyWalker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5.0f;
    public bool canJump = true;
    public float jumpHeight = 2.0f;
    public Camera playerCamera;
    public float lookSpeed = 2.0f;
    public float lookXLimit = 60.0f;


    bool grounded = false;
    Rigidbody r;
    Vector2 rotation = Vector2.zero;
    float maxVelocityChange = 10.0f;

    void Awake()
    {
        r = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        r.freezeRotation = true;
        r.useGravity = false;
        r.collisionDetectionMode = CollisionDetectionMode.ContinuousDynamic;
        rotation.y = transform.eulerAngles.y;

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (grounded)
        {
            // Calculate how fast we should be moving
            Vector3 forwardDir = Vector3.Cross(transform.up, -playerCamera.transform.right).normalized;
            Vector3 rightDir = Vector3.Cross(transform.up, playerCamera.transform.forward).normalized;
            Vector3 targetVelocity = (forwardDir * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") + rightDir * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")) * speed;

            Vector3 velocity = transform.InverseTransformDirection(r.velocity);
            velocity.y = 0;
            velocity = transform.TransformDirection(velocity);
            Vector3 velocityChange = transform.InverseTransformDirection(targetVelocity - velocity);
            velocityChange.x = Mathf.Clamp(velocityChange.x, -maxVelocityChange, maxVelocityChange);
            velocityChange.z = Mathf.Clamp(velocityChange.z, -maxVelocityChange, maxVelocityChange);
            velocityChange.y = 0;
            velocityChange = transform.TransformDirection(velocityChange);

            r.AddForce(velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

            if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && canJump)
            {
                r.AddForce(transform.up * jumpHeight, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            }

            
        }

        grounded = false;
    }

    void OnCollisionStay()
    {
        grounded = true;
    }
}
```

And here are the code for the gravity functions

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SC_PlanetGravity : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform planet;
    public bool alignToPlanet = true;

    float gravityConstant = 9.8f;
    Rigidbody r;

    void Start()
    {
        r = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 toCenter = planet.position - transform.position;
        toCenter.Normalize();

        r.AddForce(toCenter * gravityConstant, ForceMode.Acceleration);

        if (alignToPlanet)
        {
            Quaternion q = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, -toCenter);
            q = q * transform.rotation;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, q, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by having a new script added to the player avatar.

Here is the code, it's basically a copy paste of a part of the RigidBodyWalker script with some more added parts. It's not perfect but it works like I wanted it to.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InputRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera playerCamera;

    public float speed;

    public float rotationSpeed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 forwardDir = Vector3.Cross(transform.up, -playerCamera.transform.right).normalized;
        Vector3 rightDir = Vector3.Cross(transform.up, playerCamera.transform.forward).normalized;
        Vector3 targetVelocity = (forwardDir * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") + rightDir * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")) * speed;

        if(targetVelocity != Vector3.zero)
        {
            Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetVelocity, transform.up);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can propose an alternative approach which I believe will simplify the problem, should you choose. If the root of your character is positioned at the center of the planetoid, then all movement can be handled as a rotation on root and you won't be fighting the inertia of the character or needing to orient it to the planetoid. Jumping could be handled by adding another child below the root that can slide up and down. Hope this helps!